# Update the internal state of RDD elements

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm newbie in Spark and I want to update the internal state of my RDD's elements with `rdd.foreach` method, but it doesn't work. Here is my code example:

```
class Test extends Serializable{
  var foo = 0.0
  var bar = 0.0

  def updateFooBar() = {
    foo = Math.random()
    bar = Math.random()
  }
}

var testList = Array.fill(5)(new Test())
var testRDD = sc.parallelize(testList)
testRDD.foreach{ x => x.updateFooBar() }
testRDD.collect().foreach { x=> println(x.foo+"~"+x.bar) }
```

and the result is:

```
0.0~0.0
0.0~0.0
0.0~0.0
0.0~0.0
0.0~0.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RDDs are immutable by design. This design choice makes them more robust, as mutation is a common source of bugs, and it supports the "resilient" part of the RDD name (resilient distributed dataset); if a partition in a downstream RDD is lost, Spark can reconstruct it from its parents. So, it's best to think of Spark programming as construction of dataflows, even when you're not doing streaming.

On `foreach`, it's designed for "pure side effect" operations, like writing to disk, a database, or the console.